# Disable prompts for keyring

Tags: lxde, keyrings

I often get a prompt: 'An application wants to create a new keyring called "Default keyring". Choose the password you want to use for it.'

I do not want to create a keyring.

I do not want to be prompted about this all the time.

Many answers suggest entering a blank password. I cannot accept this solution because it seems to create an insecure keyring without a password.

Many answers suggest deleting files under ~/.local/share/keyrings but I do not have any files in that folder.

Many answers suggest disabling the keyring in "User Settings", "seahorse" or other places. I do not have any of these things. I have a minimal "lubuntu" install (Ubuntu+LXDE).

How else can I disable the prompts to create a keyring?

Comment: I have noticed that if you setup your system to login automatically it bypasses unlocking the keyring so when apps need it, like Google Chrome, they pop that up.  If you are the only one using your system running the keyring without a password would be fine.  If a hacker on the internet breaks into your computer, they would have the ability to change your password(s) anyway so it would be pointless.